# How do I feed a tensor in Keras model using a numpy array values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trying to feed a keras model tensor with numpy array values. But the tensor is 4D and the array is 3D. How can I to convert this 3D numpy array (128, 128, 3) in a 4D (?, 128, 128, 3) tensor?

Comment: Please post your code to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Fyi, this question will continue to show up as unanswered unless you accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy arrays as inputs to keras models. It depends on your model, but often the first dimension is the number of samples, and the last dimension is 1.

Let's say you have 1000 samples that each have an array of shape (128, 128, 3). You can combine the arrays using np.stack. Here's a simplified example:

```
a=np.array([[0,1,2],[3,4,5]])
b=np.array([[6,7,8],[9,10,11]])
c=np.stack((a,b))   #shape (2,2,3) with the first 2 representing the number of samples
```

If you want to reshape the array to have 1 as an additional final dimension (for example, changing the shape from (1000, 128, 128, 3) to (1000, 128, 128, 3, 1)), you can do:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], \
    X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3], 1)
```

This can then be passed to the model. If you have a model that requires that a tensor be passed to it, you can convert the array to a tensor. In Tensorflow, this can be done with tf.convert_to_tensor- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `np.expand_dims` to extend the first dimension. The 4D tensor means that you are having a batch of some images with 3 channels. Since you have just one image, add into an array and give it to the model or use `np.expand_dims(image_ref, axis=0)`.